# Why do I get a StringOutOfBoundsException even though I am within bounds of the String array?

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm currently attempting this problem and seem to keep getting this `StringOutOfBoundsException`, can anyone explain to me why?
When I exit the while loop, it seems that I mistyped endPtr--;

[image: StringOutOfBoundsException]

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal input!");
        }
        if (s.length() <= 1) {
            return true;
        }
        
        int startPtr = 0;
        int endPtr = s.length() - 1;
        
        while (startPtr < endPtr) {
            while (startPtr < endPtr && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(startPtr))) {
                startPtr++;
            }
            
            //ERROR while (startPtr < endPtr && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(endPtr)))  {
                //endPtr--;
            //}
            
            if (startPtr < endPtr && Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(startPtr)) != Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(endPtr))) {
                return false;
            }
        
            startPtr++;
            endPtr++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are including code, please paste it in as text.

Comment: May I suggest that you put a System.out.println() statement inside the while loop to find the value of endPtr? Or use a debugger.

Comment: Because endPtr is either below 0 or at the length of the string or higher. some simple debugging will tell you which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of the main loop, you are incrementing endPtr.

```
    startPtr++;
    endPtr++;
```

By doing so, you are positionning the end of your String after its real ending.

And here comes the error.

And also, you are creating an infinite loop because the condition

```
while (startPtr < endPtr)
```

will always be true.

Comment: I would add that you should use different variables for browsing your String :
Two for the main loop and different ones for the secondary loops. Otherwise, your program will get confused.